# "start" and "The system cannot find the file"

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to use the command [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

For example, I have the programs **Firefox** and **HxD** installed on my system

```
C:\Users\Steven>forfiles -s -p "C:\Program Files (x86)" -m firefox.exe

"firefox.exe"

C:\Users\Steven>forfiles -s -p "C:\Program Files (x86)" -m HxD.exe

"HxD.exe"
```

and my path

```
C:\Users\Steven>path
PATH=C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\system32\wbem;
```

However I can launch Firefox but not HxD

```
C:\Users\Steven>start firefox

C:\Users\Steven>start HxD
The system cannot find the file HxD.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is probably registered with Windows as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically, note the use of the

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

key.

**UPDATE**

A little experimentation (using Notepad++ which I have installed but is *not* in my path) reveals that the "App Paths" key isn't consulted when launching the program from the command line directly. It *does*, however work with the START command.

Comment: Bill, see my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/512553/138343 "CMD - Why “start winword” works but just “winword” doesn't").