# How does the windows START command know where to grab programs from?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

For instance, if I want to start Google Chrome,

```
start chrome
```

will suffice. But I don't have chrome on my `PATH`, so using

```
chrome
```

will not work. How does [START](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) know where Chrome is? And if [START](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) can't find Chrome, how can I help it find Chrome?

Comment: Compare this: [*How does the Windows run dialog locate executables?*](https://superuser.com/q/87372/432690) I cannot tell if it applies to `start` though.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the correct missing piece - I changed the chrome.exe location to chrome2.exe, and `START` can no longer find Chrome.

Comment: See also [“start” and “The system cannot find the file”](https://superuser.com/q/566828/354511).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/512546/why-does-start-winword-work-but-just-winword-doesnt/512553#512553 is better than my original answer. My answer only has the benefit of being a literal quote from Microsoft's page on the subject.