# Creating a system variable

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables

I would like to get some suggestion regarding adding an entry to the PATH variable under System Variables.

Whenever I install a program on my windows machine, I end up adding the path to the program to the "PATH" variable in the "System Variable" section. So, now I have pretty long value for the PATH variable (It's no problem, I know). But, I wonder if there is a more elegant/standard way of doing this.

Comment: Do you really need to add *every* installed program to the PATH? If so, why?

Comment: Just to have it available from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do three things to make it more tidy :

1. Rename your Program files to c:\apps in the registry. This means new programs will install here. Thus the path will look cleaner
2. keep a few system variables that are not used except as aprts of the the main path var
   So you have PATHA1 with 
   c:\my folder1\app1;c:\apps\app2\;c:\program files\something here

and PATHA2 similarly,

```
c:\apps\app2;c:\apps\app3\;c:\program files\something here
```

some might over lap PATHB1

etc then in your real PATH var use only one or two of these predefined vars!

Meaning PATH will be defined as

```
%PATHA1%;%PATHB2%
```

3. where apps force a folder with a space in it but allow you to edit the install folder like c:\apps\my large path\ change it to

   c:\apps\shortTLA\

Answer (score 0):

I don't think renaming your **Program Files** or **Program Files (x86)** directories is such a great idea. As you said, a long PATH string is not really a problem, but if you want to avoid doing so I'd recommend one of the following approaches:

### I. Using Batch Files

1. Create a directory such as **C:\Progs**
2. Create simple batch files similar to the following in the directory, one per program:

   ```
   @start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company Name\ProgramName.exe" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
   ```
3. Save each batch file with the same name as the program's EXE, such as **ProgramName.bat**, although of course you can also name it something shorter and easier to remember such as **PN.bat**
4. Finally, add **C:\Progs** to your PATH

### II. Using App Paths

1. Create .REG files similar to the following, one per program:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\ProgramName.exe]
   @="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Company Name\\ProgramName.exe"
   "Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Company Name"
   ```
2. Double-click each .REG file and import into the registry (after which the file can be discarded)
3. Here too you can use a shorter and easier to remember alias by replacing

   ```
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\ProgramName.exe]
   ```

   with

   ```
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\PN.exe]
   ```

You can see how the second method works by checking out my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/512553/138343). The only minor disadvantage with it is that while you can invoke the program using **ProgramName** (or **PN**) from the Run dialog, you'll need to use `start ProgramName` (or `start PN`) at the command prompt.